# Add EventListener to function?

Tags: actionscript-3

Quick question... Is is possible to attach an EventListener to a function? Such that if at any point in a function's execution an Event is Dispatched the EventHandler will get fired?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event listeners are attached to objects that belong to a class that descends from EventDispatcher. You cannot attach them to a function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the stage to dispatch such an event and listen to it:

```
stage.addEventListener("myFunctionWasCalled", callback);
myFunction();

public function callback(event:Event):void {
    trace("callback executed");
}

public function myFunction():void {
    stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("myFunctionWasCalled"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply passing a function reference (callback) as an argument

```
function cb(s:String):void {
   trace(s);
}

function doit(f:Function):void {
   // do something
   f("Hi");
   // do some more stuff
}

doit(cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to listen for a event in the lifetime of a function call just add/remove as needed. 
example:

```
function somefunction():void{
    someobject.addEventListener(Event, eventhandler);
    ... doing stuff
    someobject.removeEventListener(Event, eventhandler);
}
```

Now keep in mind if your doing this then your choice in even flows may become very hard to track down the road.

Typicality you only really need to worry about this in the life and death of a object vs the life and death of a function call.

Answer (score 0):

To attach an event listener to an object this object must implement `IEventDispatcher` interface. So you could extend `Function` class and add your methods. AS3 docs say that `Function` is not final, but AS3 compile disagrees with it: `VerifyError: Error #1103: Class Bla cannot extend final base class.`

So, the short answer is: **you can't attach an event listener to a function**.

But as it was already mentioned you could:

1. Pass callback/callbacks to the function which will be called at some point: `function bla(callback1:Function, callback2:Function):void`.
2. Dispatch events from some other object during function execution, for example you could make a `Functor` class which has method `execute()` and implements `IEventDispatcher`. In this way you'd call the function `myFunctor.execute()` and could get dispatched events.